# Javascript error using DT package in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, dt

This is my first post, and I'm probably doing something silly to create this error ... I am running R 4.2.1 in RStudio, version 2022.07.1, built 554 ("Spotted Wakerobin"). Using a built-in dataset, here is a reproducible example:

```
table(esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp, dnn = c("age", "alc")) |>
  DT::datatable(
    options = list(
      scrollY = FALSE)
  )
```

I am getting a Javascript Alert. In case the image doesn't appear, it says,

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0, column 4. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I read that page, and I wonder if it means there is a combination of values that does not exist in the dataset. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you are doing something silly - running the same code works for me. I don't know how to fix this but you might want to try to work out if this is a problem with your RStudio Viewer, or something else, by running the code outside of RStudio, e.g. in a vanilla R session or in another IDE.

Comment: Thank you for checking, @SamR. I opened the R gui and ran the code, and I got the same error. I had just updated R and RStudio last week. I wonder if it's a difference in versions of the software.

Comment: When I run the code, I get the same warning on Fedora Linux 35, R 4.1.3 and DT 0.23. Both in RStudio and in the console

Comment: What is your package version?

Comment: Good question, @shs. It's version 0.23, which appears to be the latest. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/index.html

Comment: I don't believe you can cross-tabulate the data in that way, for DataTables to consume. DataTables does try to build a HTML table with 5 `<td>` columns per `<tr>` data row, but only receives 4 values in each row array - hence the warning message about that missing vallue in `column 4` (the 5th column in the HTML table).  I expect there is a way to massage the data, so DataTables can use it the way you want - but I don't know enough R for that.

Comment: (You can see the raw data with no warnings using nothing more than `DT::datatable(esoph)`.)

Comment: @andrewJames in my example I wanted to see the crosstabs for only two of the three variables in esoph. With this suggested code I can get row counts only for all combinations of the three variables. I really think the problem is that I have cells with no data. I ran similar code on a research study where I looked at the crosstabs of assigned group and sex of babies -- no problem, got what I wanted -- then I ran the same procedure with the crosstabs of assigned group and reported race of babies. I got the error with that analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a work colleague about this problem, and she came up with this solution: Converting the table to a data frame, then pivoting wider:

```
table(agegp = esoph$agegp, alcgp = esoph$alcgp) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = alcgp, values_from = Freq) |> 
  DT::datatable(options = list(scrollY = FALSE))
```

Thank you to all who replied.